# How to solve the duplicate subscription (Subscribe.OnSubscribe()) error in listener code in azure eventhubs with Ktor (Kotlin server)?

Tags: azure, kotlin, azure-eventhub, ktor

The error is:

**Duplicate Subscription has been detected.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spec. Rule 2.12 - Subscriber.onSubscribe MUST NOT be called more than once (based on object equality)**
This is the error that I'm getting on the listener side in azure eventhubs with ktor server.
The error is in the PARTITION_PROCESSOR part. How do you solve this error?

```
package com.example.eventhub

import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventProcessorClientBuilder
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.checkpointstore.blob.BlobCheckpointStore
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.models.PartitionContext
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClientBuilder
import java.util.function.Consumer
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.models.EventContext
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.models.ErrorContext
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventData

class AzureEventHubClient {

    fun listenEvent() {

        val blobContainerAsyncClient = BlobContainerClientBuilder()
            .connectionString("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[[ REDACTED ]];AccountKey=[[ REDACTED ]];EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net")
            .containerName("[[ REDACTED ]]")
            .buildAsyncClient()        

        val PARTITION_PROCESSOR: Consumer<EventContext> = Consumer<EventContext> { eventContext ->
            val partitionContext: PartitionContext = eventContext.partitionContext
            val eventData: EventData = eventContext.eventData
            System.out.printf(
                "Processing event from partition %s with sequence number %d with body: %s%n",
                partitionContext.partitionId, eventData.sequenceNumber, eventData.bodyAsString
            )

            // Every 10 events received, it will update the checkpoint stored in Azure Blob Storage.
            if (eventContext.getEventData().getSequenceNumber().toInt() % 5 === 0) {
            eventContext.updateCheckpoint()
            }
        }

        val ERROR_HANDLER: Consumer<ErrorContext> = Consumer<ErrorContext> { errorContext ->
            println(
                "Error occurred in partition processor for partition ::" + errorContext.partitionContext.partitionId
            )
        }
        val clientConnectionString: String =
            "Endpoint=sb://[[ REDACTED ]].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=[[ REDACTED ]];SharedAccessKey=[[ REDACTED ]];EntityPath=[[ REDACTED ]]"
        
        val eventProcessorClientBuilder = EventProcessorClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(clientConnectionString, "[[ REDACTED ]]")
            .consumerGroup(EventHubClientBuilder.DEFAULT_CONSUMER_GROUP_NAME)
            .processEvent(PARTITION_PROCESSOR)
            .processError(ERROR_HANDLER)
            .checkpointStore(BlobCheckpointStore(blobContainerAsyncClient))

        // Use the builder object to create an event processor client
        val eventProcessorClient = eventProcessorClientBuilder.buildEventProcessorClient()

        println("Starting event processor")
        eventProcessorClient.start()
        println("Press enter to stop.")        
        Thread.sleep(150000)
        println("Stopping event processor")
        eventProcessorClient.stop()
        println("Event processor stopped.")

        println("Exiting process")

    }
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that your original post leaked sensitive details about your environment, including your shared key information.   I've redacted them in an edit, but please be sure to consider them compromised and roll the keys immediately.

Comment: I have yet to see this error because we shouldn't be resubscribing to any objects. I would need more information to understand/reproduce what is going on. You can file an issue here with repro steps: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues